# Why is m2e putting the wrong version of some artifacts into the .classpath file?

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse 2021-12 on Windows.  I work almost exclusively on Java (1.8) Maven projects that are stored in Git.

I noticed that a project that I just started looking at (cloned it from our central repo) was getting a weird runtime error that didn't make sense.  The error made it seem like it was referencing an older version of one artifact.  I checked the maven dependencies both from the "Dependency Hierarchy" view and from the command line with "mvn dependency:tree". Both confirmed that I had the correct version of the artifact.

However, the .classpath file, along with the "Libraries" tab in "Java Build Path" had the previous version of the same artifact.

I tried "Update Project" with "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checked.  No change.

I then went down the rabbit hole, deleting the project, then the Eclipse dot files, and then reimported the project from the git repo.  That made it even worse. It didn't even acknowledge it was a Java project.  I couldn't figure out how to fix this (outside of simply manually editing the .project file, which will be a last resort), so I enabled "Faceted Form", and that came out with Java automatically selected.  Then I noticed it didn't even think it was a Maven project, even though it had selected the proper source directories. I selected making it a Maven project.  And finally, that just got me back to where I started, with the wrong version of the artifact specified in the .classpath file.

Finally, I made a copy of the .classpath file and simply manually edited it.  I found several artifacts with the same problem.  And by "same", I mean several artifacts all developed internally, which should have been at version "2.6.0", which is what is specified in the pom hierarchy, were set to version "2.5.0".

I then ran the service, and it ran fine.

I have no idea whether there are any other discrepancies, being differences between the Maven-specified version and the version in the .classpath file.  That would require more thorough examination. I used to think that situation would have been impossible.

**Update**:

From the comments, I decided to step through this again more carefully, noting the results at each step.

I first deleted the existing Eclipse project, without deleting the project contents on disk.  I then copied and removed the .classpath, .project, and .settings.  I then imported the project from the Git repo.  It auto-detected "Maven" for "Import as".  I had "Detect and configured project natures" checked.

This resulted in a Maven project, but not a Java project, so it didn't even generate a .classpath file.  The .project file only had the "maven2Nature" and associated builder.  This somewhat explains why the Maven import didn't generate the correct .classpath entries.

At this point, the only way I know to make it figure out it is a Java project, outside of manually editing the .project file, is to convert to Faceted form.  This successfully added the "javanature" and associated builder, and detected src/main/java and src/test/java, but I still don't have any dependencies.

At this point, I tried "Update Project" with "Force" checked. That did nothing.  I tried "Disable workspace resolution" (which I want anyway). That did nothing.

It's possible that my most recent attempt got an almost sane .classpath file by using "mvn eclipse:eclipse".  I know, it's supposed to be a bad idea, but sometimes it seems like the only thing that works.

It appears that the key here is that the Maven import from Git doesn't first detect it's a Java project.

Just in case, I did it all again, doing a top-level "File->Import->Existing Maven Project", with almost exactly the same result.  The import from git created the project name as the git repository name, and the import from Existing created the project name as the project name from the pom.xml, the two of which are only different by case.  Otherwise, the result was identical.

I then tried again, with no dot files, and I copied in an almost empty .project file, removing all but the java nature and builder.  I tried doing git import, but that didn't auto-detect Maven, so I went back to Import Existing Maven Project, but that resulted in a brain-damaged Java project.  I'm guessing the way I did it made it so that it didn't know what Java compiler to use, so it couldn't find "java.lang.Object".

I then started over again, removed the dot files, imported from git (auto-detects Maven), then converted to Faceted form, which auto-added Java nature, then ran "mvn eclipse:eclipse" from the command line.  This brought me back to an almost correct configuration, with several artifacts with the almost correct version, with all references using M2_REPO.

This makes it clear it wasn't m2e that was producing the incorrect version numbers, but the "eclipse" plugin.  M2e didn't even produce a .classpath file, because it didn't know it was a Java project.

**Update**:

I believe I've found the element in the original pom.xml such that when this project is imported, m2e doesn't acknowledge it is a Java project, which results in no .classpath file being created.

Before I post what I found, I wanted to say that I didn't write this, I'm just trying to figure out why it's broken.  The thing that someone put in here is something I would never do, and I had noticed it earlier, but it didn't occur to me it would result in what I've been seeing.

What I found in plugins was a "lifecycle-mapping" plugin, looking like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[3.8.0,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action> <ignore></ignore> </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I change nothing else in the pom.xml but comment this out, importing this project works correctly.

Frankly, I don't really know why some people in my org do this.  I think they must give up trying to properly configure m2e, and this is just a way to get rid of the red Xs (even if it doesn't actually fix anything).

Obviously, the fix is to just remove this, but I'd appreciate any background anyone could provide on why someone might do this, and what they should be doing instead.

Comment: Are your eclipse configuration files stored in git?

Comment: Good question. They are not.

Comment: When recreating a maven project, use Maven -> import project.  (Preferably on an already checked out project. ). Otherwise the maven magic does not kick in.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Smart import detects Maven projects for years.

Comment: @howlger then help him.  If you can.

Comment: The `.classpath` file should refer to `org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER`  rather to specific dependencies. In the _Project Explorer_ the project should have _Maven Dependencies_ rather than _Referenced Libraries_. Otherwise the `.classpath` file is probably broken by referring dependencies directly instead via m2e derived from the POM.

Comment: You may also want to check if the project builds and runs from the command line. I’ve seen undefined behavior if the build was broken.

Comment: @howlger , ok, what could have caused it to generate "M2_REPO/" path entries instead of using MCC? I have a bunch of different Maven projects cloned to my local git tree. I find that most of them reference MCC, and only a handful reference M2_REPO, although those are all ones that I've directly worked on. Many of the MCC ones I've only looked at or worked on briefly. I guess I'm going to save off what I have and go through the process again. Sorry I didn't mention it, but it does build fine from the command line.

Comment: I've updated the post with more details on each import scenario I tried.

Comment: Interesting.  Is this a publicly accessible git repository?

Comment: Sorry, no. It would likely take a lot of work to figure out what in this project is causing these symptoms. I would think figuring out why import from git isn't detecting Java would be straightforward for someone familiar with the internals. It seems like that's the most important issue. The eclipse plug in shouldn't be relied on, if possible.

Comment: To my understanding `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is from a time long before eclipse got good built-in maven support and should not be used today.

Comment: Yes, I think we've already established that.

Comment: tl;dr https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please

Comment: First step would probably be downloading and unzipping a fresh copy of the latest Eclipse so you know that the platform you have problems with is not broken with, and then repeat the "Maven -> Import existing" bit into a new and fresh workspace.

Comment: Yes, @howlger, it would be great if I could produce an isolated test for case maven import failing to detect java, but I have no idea why it is doing this. I've tried with a couple of "hello world" projects generated from spring.io, but none of those display the symptom. There are multiple people in my organization seeing the same problem.

Comment: I at least have more things to try. I'm going in the reverse direction, with a dummy copy of my original service, simply removing things from it and reimporting each time. It doesn't need to fully compile, it just needs to know it's a Java app. I'm almost down to the external sample, and it's still showing the symptom.

Comment: Ok. I now know what is causing the "Import Maven Project" step to not detect it is Java. I commented out a "lifecycle-mapping" plugin that someone had put into the pom.xml, for reasons I'm not aware of, and when I import it now, it detects it is Java, and properly uses the single "MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER" in the .classpath instead of multiple M2_REPO entries for every dependency. I can update the post with more info now, but as this now is a different issue than I originally posted, I could also create a new post for this.